# Bunch of errors messages in Android.Manifext.xml

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio

I was trying to connect my project with firebase and got these bunch of errors in my Android.Manifest.xml file
I am pasting the image of my Android.Manifest.xml file
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGrWk.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

these are in the red color because you are not in the android environment. When you will be in the android development environment these will be gone. Because your environment is now set for the flutter that's why you are seeing this.

Comment: would yo please tell me how to change environment in android studio. I am a bit new to android development

Comment: well, it depends upon if you have opened a flutter project or an android project

Comment: can I run flutter commands in an android project?

Comment: nope,
you can run flutter commands in a flutter project according to my knowledge